# Recursive Definitions

Tags: recursion, racket, r5rs

I'm currently learning about recursion in Scheme. I found this recursive definition but I don't understand what it is trying to do. If someone could explain it to me, I would appreciate it. Here is the definition:

```
(define (function ls)
    (if (null? ls) '()
        (append
            (map (lambda (x) (cons (car ls) x))
                 (function (cdr ls))
            )
            (function (cdr ls))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current state, `function` simply returns the empty list, *no matter the input*. However, it *does* ring a bell. It looks like a failed attempt to implement the [`powerset`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) function:

```
(define (powerset ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '(())
      (append (map (lambda (x) (cons (car ls) x))
                   (powerset (cdr ls)))
              (powerset (cdr ls)))))
```

Can you spot the difference? the base case in your code is wrong! In case you were wondering, `powerset` returns the set of all possible subsets of a list:

```
(powerset '(1 2 3))
=> '((1 2 3) (1 2) (1 3) (1) (2 3) (2) (3) ())
```